# Asp.NET Core Restful API -Problem add api-controller with actions by using entity framework

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core

I defined a code first database context.
In the startup.cs i call

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

      
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        
            var connstr = Configuration.GetConnectionString("ElLocalDB");
            services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connstr));
            
        }
```

Aftr Choosen new-->Add controller with actions by using entity framework i choosed my model class and the database context

As i try to add a new controller, i get the message:

> A named connection string was used, but the name 'ElLocalDB' was not
> found in the application´s configuration. Note that named connection
> strings are only supported when using 'Iconfiguration' and service
> proider, such as in a typical asp.net core application...

What can i do?

Comment: The application configuration which is xml format doesn't contain the database ELocalDB.  You need to edit the configuration (can be done with notepad) and update to correct the connection string.

Comment: Look for web.config.xml... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/configuring/connection-strings#use-code-first-with-connection-string-in-appconfigwebconfig-file